# Como poner el order by en la query

Tags: java, sql

Tengo una consulta SQL en java y necesito ordenar por nombre, pero por el tema de las comillas simples y dobles, no me queda claro si lo hago bien.

El código es el siguiente:

```
 public ArrayList paisesEnUnContinente (int id) {
        ArrayList<Pais> data = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet res;
            res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pais WHERE IdContinente = " + id +"' order by Nombre");
            while (res.next()) {
                Pais p = new Pais();
                p.setIdCont(res.getInt("IdContinente"));
                p.setNombrePais(res.getString("Nombre"));
                p.setMillonesHab(res.getInt("Millones_habitantes"));
                data.add(p);
            }
            orden.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está bien, solo te sobra una comilla simple antes del `order`.

```
"SELECT * FROM pais WHERE IdContinente = " + id + " order by Nombre"
```